# quasar q-checkbox does not get checked on data edit

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar, qcheckbox

All,

I have edit record scenario in which checkboxes not automatically gets selected based on the model data. As shown in the image, I have debug display for the checkbox model. Does quasar support checked data automatically from model or do I need to anything special in my code? I tried few thing but nothing looks clean. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Below is my checkbox code segment in a child component. The child component is used in many parent pages. I have used v-model in other cases just like in the [quasar example](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/checkbox#Example--Array-as-model) and checkboxes work fine on the parent page. In my case, I am trying to use group checkboxes in child component and sync the values to the parent page. It looks like an alternate solution for me is to duplicate checkboxes in all parent pages. Even with the child component approach, the primary scenario works good - meaning data creating/insert where I can check/uncheck checkbox value and record save works fine. My issue is in the secondary scenario - where I am trying to edit the record by pulling saved data, in this scenario all data elements get prefilled ok except group checkboxes.

> ```
>     <div>
>       <q-field
>         :value="durations"
>         label="Select duration option"
>         stack-label
>         ref="durations"
>         :rules="[durationRule]"
>       >
>         <template v-slot:control>
>           <q-checkbox
>             :value="durations"
>             val="30"
>             label="30 min"
>             @input="$emit('update:durations', $event)"
>           />
>           <q-checkbox
>             :value="durations"
>             val="60"
>             label="60 min"
>             @input="$emit('update:durations', $event)"
>           />
>           <q-checkbox
>             :value="durations"
>             val="120"
>             label="120 min"
>             @input="$emit('update:durations', $event)"
>           />
>         </template>
>       </q-field>
>     </div>
> ```

Comment: Resolved my issue. Root cause if my issue is that I store checkbox value as Integer in the DB [30, 60, 120], but in UI checkbox value should be String ["30","60","120"]. I fixed it by changing DB values as String!

Comment: You can store values as integers by using `:val="30"` (mind colon)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a Vue3 change or not, but I could not get @input to trigger anything from a q-checkbox to save my life. This code was me trying to merge two q-table examples together, I wanted the expanding rows AND the checboxes multi-select down the left. If you start from the working multi-select and then add the expansion row, the expansion row substitution breaks the checkboxes, so I wanted to put them back in. I had to find another post about watchers to realize that I could use the array that was being updated by the q-checkbox to then trigger my custom code, the trick was to watch **deep** (like into the abyss...):

```
  //The array attached to v-model on my q-checkboxes
watch: {
 rChecked: {
  handler: function (val, oldVal) { 
    var x,intTrue=0;
    for(x=0;x<this.rChecked.length;x++) {
      if(this.rChecked[x]==true)
        intTrue++;
    }
    if(intTrue==this.rChecked.length) {
      this.bCheckAll=true;
    } 
    else if(intTrue==0) this.bCheckAll=false;
    else this.bCheckAll="maybe";
  },
  deep: true
 },
},
```

The quasar components:

```
<q-table
  :rows="GetFoldersInPath"
  :columns="columns"
  :pagination="FolderPagination"
  row-key="name"
  class="full-width"
  selection="multiple"
  v-model:selected="selected"
>
  <template v-slot:header="props">
    <q-tr :props="props" :style="{'background-color':Theme.SideBG}">
      <q-th
        v-for="col in props.cols"
        :key="col.name"
        :props="props"
        :rowspan="(col.name=='name' || col.name=='location_path' || col.name=='last_value' ? 2 : 1)"
      >
        <div v-if="col.name=='id'" style="display:inline-block;"><q-checkbox v-model="bCheckAll" /></div>
        {{col.label}}
      </q-th>
    </q-tr>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:body="props">
    <q-tr :props="props" @click.stop="props.expand = !props.expand" style="cursor:pointer;">
      <q-td
        v-for="col, in props.cols"
        :key="col.name"
        :props="props"
        style="padding:4px 10px;"
      >
        <q-checkbox v-if="col.name=='id'" v-model="rChecked[props.rowIndex]" />
        {{ col.value }} 
      </q-td>
    </q-tr>
  </template>
</q-table>
```

And no, this isn't directly tied to the above, but this was a close match to what I was looking for so I thought I'd drop the solution here. Hope it helps someone else!